# Apply threshold for numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a model predictions type of `numpy.ndarray`
The predictions looks like

```
y_pred = array([[0.25602802, 0.74397198],
       [0.33962464, 0.66037536],
       [0.95954497, 0.04045503],
       [0.11751671, 0.88248329],
       [0.6809288 , 0.3190712 ],
       [0.6648042 , 0.3351958 ],
       [0.21672122, 0.78327878],
       [0.52893726, 0.47106274],
       [0.45118992, 0.54881008],
       [0.36868405, 0.63131595]])
```

where the first value of inner array corresponds to 0 class and the second value corresponds to 1 class. For this `y_pred` i need to apply FNR `threshold` `0.21552509277542697`, which i also calculated. That is the efficient numpy way to do it ?

The result should be in `predict` interface. For example for pair `[0.6824846 , 0.3175154 ]` result should `1` because `0.3175154` > `threshold 0.21552509277542697`. For pair `[0.95894656, 0.04105344]` the result should be `0` because `0.04045503` < `threshold` `0.21552509277542697`

I expect the result looks like

```
array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1])
```

Comment: y_pred_th = y_pred[:, 0] > threshold; FNR = (y_pred_th*y_true).sum()/len(y_pred_th)

Comment: @yannziselman Thank you for your answer, i edited the question for better clarification

Comment: predict = (y_pred[:, 1] > threshold).astype(int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mask based on both columns looks like this:

```
(y_pred > threshold).all(1)
```

The result is an array of booleans. You can sum booleans to get an integer, or use them as an index. If you absolutely insist on getting zeros and ones, you can convert to integer, e.g.:

```
(y_pred > threshold).all(1).astype(int)
```

Without copying any data, you can do:

```
(y_pred > threshold).all(1).view(np.uint8)
```